# NodeJS streaming array as argument to request

Tags: node.js, stream, node-request

I have an array of parameters, which I then transform into an array of urls.
I would like to then stream this array of urls to request.

```
var parameters = [1,2,.., n]
var urls = [];
parameters.forEach(function(item) {
    urls.push('http://www.example.com/page'+item)
})
```

Using the module event-stream I can transform this array into a stream like this:

```
var es = require('event-stream');
var reader = es.readArray(urls);
```

I can then do:

```
reader.pipe(process.stdout)
```

I know how to use `request` so I can pipe its result like this:

```
 request(url).pipe(csvToJson).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('destinationFile'))
```

But how can I stream the array of urls into request, if that's possible?

Comment: Make `csvToJson` some `data` object and then maybe key them like `var data = { csv: csvToJson, urls: urls }`

Comment: I may have been unclear, basically given an array of urls I would like to `urls.forEach(function(url) { request(url)}).pipe(csvToJson).pipe(transform).pipe(destination)` My problem is how to pipe the urls individually into the request function/module?